# Serializer to filter relations base on arbitrary attributes

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to DRF, what I have works but I am interested if there is a better way to do it:

I have a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` serializer to enumerate a many-to-many relation.  It works fine, i.e.:

```
mobile_forms = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
  allow_empty=True,
  many=True,
  queryset=MobileForm.objects.all(),
  required=False)
```

My question is that for this relation, I always only want to return related items that have their deleted status set to `False`. In order to achieve this I am doing:

```
active_mobile_forms = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
def get_active_mobile_forms(self, obj):
         return obj.mobile_forms.filter(Q(deleted=False)).values_list('pk',flat=True)
```

It seems wrong to me to have to create a separate serializer to filter the objects returned.  Based on my understanding of the `queryset` argument to the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` is used to validate input, so it is not appropriate to filter here.

Basically, I'm interested in the best practice for filtering a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` relation when objects are returned via a serializer. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `SerializerMethodField`, its main feature is to overload `to_representation` to incorporate the new get method you just set:

```
    def to_representation(self, value):
        method = getattr(self.parent, self.method_name)
        return method(value)
```

So, if you don't want to use a `SerializerMethodField`, you can just overload `to_representation` on your serializer yourself to your liking.  Something like:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    mobile_forms = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['mobile_forms'] = [x for x in representation['mobile_forms'] if {arbitrary_characteristic}]
        return representation
```

Edited to add: Don't forget to `return` `representation`!

Comment: you are awesome, thank you.  This is exactly what I was looking for.